# question about System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

I use a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control in my application:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser objBrowser;
```

Anywhere my `objBrowser` navigated, I want it to have this javascript function:

```
function alert(message)
{
  window.external.handleMessage(message);
}
```

that overrides alert function.

When i use this:

```
private void objBrowser_DocumentCompleted(
    object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  objBrowser.Url = new Uri(
    "javascript:function alert(message){window.external.handleMessage(message);};");

  objBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("alert", new object[] { "hello" });//line 1
}

public void handleMessage(object obj)
{
  string msg = obj.ToString();
}
```

alert function in java script doesn't pass the message into my form. But when i use this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  objBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("alert", new object[] { "hello" });
}

private void objBrowser_DocumentCompleted(
    object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  objBrowser.Url = new Uri(
    "javascript:function alert(message){window.external.handleMessage(message);};");
}

public void handleMessage(object obj)
{
  string msg = obj.ToString();
}
```

and click on `button1` my form's handleMessage method executed with a object that contains "hello" string.

I want to override alert function in java script in any page that objBrowser will navigate.

How can I do this?

Comment: @qau: I reformatted your code to avoid scrollbars. You can review my changes and revert in case you disagree.

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
Private Sub webDest_Navigated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles webDest.Navigated
    injectAlertBlocker()

End Sub
Sub injectAlertBlocker()
    Dim head As HtmlElement = webDest.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
    Dim scriptEl As HtmlElement = webDest.Document.CreateElement("script")
    Dim element As IHTMLScriptElement = CType(scriptEl.DomElement, IHTMLScriptElement)
    Dim alertBlocker As String = "window.alert = function () { }"
    element.text = alertBlocker
    head.AppendChild(scriptEl)
End Sub
```